# Microsoft Graph API - Patch user (permission issue for Application Token)

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I am updating an user's password via nodejs-graph-API application(with Application token) with below endpoint

`PATCH /users/{userId}`

```
{
  passwordProfile: {
    forceChangePasswordNextSignIn: true,
    password: newPassword,
 }
```

I provided all the application, delegated access

`User.ReadWrite.All, User.ManageIdentities.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I do have two tenants (one for dev and another one for prod) in dev tenant things working fine but  it failing in prod tenant

Error:

`Error: Could not update password. Error: Authorization_RequestDenied`

Permission screen
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try giving your App the Global Admin role and see if you can update the user or not?

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma already its there, attached new image to description.

App admin, Cloud App admin, reports reader

Comment: Suresh, Please give the global administrator role only, not App admin, Cloud App admin, reports reader.

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma any idea like how much time it takes for permission to propagate?

One more than how its working my another tenant where there is no global admin permission

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma providing Global Admin Role worked out but I am in a situation where I shouldn't use it (instead should provide appropriate one)

Comment: @ShivaKeshavVarma Authentication administrator role also does the job.
Maybe you post it as answer and ll accept it :)

Comment: Glad to here that it worked for you :)-

Comment: I was struggling with a similar requirement editing one flag on AD users with Graph API. Found that "user administrator" or "authentication administrator" only works when you modify regular users' attributes. If you need to call the PATCH operation to set an attribute on a user which is not a regular user (like global admin), then you will need global admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few cases where we cannot modify other user's data simply like that. Not just the permissions of API modify but also we need to be having a proper role to do some operation. As we are modifying the other user's password we should be having the highest or related role that can do it. I used to give Global Admin role which worked in my case.

As @Suresh suggested we can also use Authentication administrator role as it worked for him.

For permission to add to application may take few seconds time as it depends on different factors like internet etc.,